# ObjectiveRecord nil model error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, cocoapods

For the first time I'm trying to use CocoaPods and ObjectiveRecord. [ObjectiveRecord's github page](https://github.com/mneorr/ObjectiveRecord)

When I try to save my object, I get the following error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01aae5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018318b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreData                            0x00023b0e -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator initWithManagedObjectModel:] + 398
    3   ObjectiveRecordTest                 0x00003691 -[CoreDataManager persistentStoreCoordinatorWithStoreType:storeURL:] + 193
    4   ObjectiveRecordTest                 0x000030f9 -[CoreDataManager persistentStoreCoordinator] + 169
    5   ObjectiveRecordTest                 0x00002dba -[CoreDataManager managedObjectContext] + 106
    6   ObjectiveRecordTest                 0x00003f26 +[NSManagedObjectContext(ActiveRecord) defaultContext] + 86
    7   ObjectiveRecordTest                 0x0000477a +[NSManagedObject(ActiveRecord) create] + 58
    8   ObjectiveRecordTest                 0x00002112 -[ViewController savePressed:] + 82
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01843874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    10  UIKit                               0x005a10c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    11  UIKit                               0x005a104e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    12  UIKit                               0x006990c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    13  UIKit                               0x00699484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    14  UIKit                               0x00698733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    15  UIKit                               0x005de51d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    16  UIKit                               0x005df184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    17  UIKit                               0x005b2e86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    18  UIKit                               0x0059d18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01a3783f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01a371cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01a5429e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01a53ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01a538db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x02e9e9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x02e9e809 GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x0059fd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  ObjectiveRecordTest                 0x000028ad main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x02b4070d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is what my Podfile looks like:

```
platform :ios
pod 'ObjectiveRecord'
```

I'm using the new xcworkspace file instead of the old xcode project file and I've imported the following two in the .pch file:

```
#import "ObjectiveRecord.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

I've added Core Data in the project's settings page. Now when I'm using the provided code from the example of the github page:

```
Person *john = [Person create];
john.name = @"John";
[john save];
```

I get the error above. Have I forgotten something? I've been searching for some time now but I can't figure it out.

I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and iOS 7.

**Update:**
It turns out that, in the general project settings, in the frameworks and libraries section, there is a red "libPods.a" entry. That means that it's missing, right? Could this be the issue?

Comment: Do you have .xcdatamodeld file in your project?

Comment: The error says you can't create the Core Data model at run time. How you do that with ObjectiveRecord, I have no idea.

Comment: Yes, the .xcdatamodeld file is there, as well as my Person.h object file.

Comment: I notices that a "libPods.a" file seems to be missing. I updated the question. Please have a look. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the error by renaming my Model.xcdatamodeld into appname.xcdatamodeld. I'm not sure why it fixed it but, I always named my models "Model" before, without any problems, but now it works. I hope this helps other people having this problem. I as well found out that the red colored "libPods.a" entry doesn't mean that it's missing. So even if it's red, everything is fine.

Comment: you can set custom model name instead of renaming. then the error will be fixed

Comment: Where can I set the custom model name?

Answer (score 5):

From the doc:

**Custom CoreData model or .sqlite database**

*If you've added the Core Data manually, you can change the custom model and database name on CoreDataManager*

```
[CoreDataManager sharedManager].modelName = @"MyModelName";
[CoreDataManager sharedManager].databaseName = @"custom_database_name";
```

https://github.com/mneorr/ObjectiveRecord/blob/master/README.md
Reading docs will always help.